# JavaScript new Date('[Date String]') doesn't understand : between timezone offset

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I have a hidden field in asp.net razor page that hold datetimeoffset value and i used it in JavaScript to create date object from. so in Chrome is working like a charm but in IE and Firefox. I found the silly mistake. It is : between hour and minutes in offset. JavaScript in IE and Firefox understand +0330 but can't parse +03:30 and i don't know how can i format date time to change to this shape. z, zz, zzz and K just return offset az +00:00 not in +0000.

```
new Date("11-20-2010 15:00:00 +03:30") Working in Chrome but in IE and Firefox
new Date("11-20-2010 15:00:00 +0330") Working in all
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `"11-20-2010 15:00:00 +03:30".replace(/:([^:]*)$/,'$1');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String parsing of dates in JavaScript is highly implementation specific.  You are going to find *many* more issues than just this one, depending on both browser and version of the browser.  You can find some of the variations [in the charts here](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html).

To have true cross-browser consistency in date parsing, you will need to forgo using the `Date` constructor with a string.  Instead, parse the string yourself or use a library.

The best library for this (IMHO) is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

```
// You would parse your string like this
var m = moment("11-20-2010 15:00:00 +03:30","MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss Z");

// If you need a Date object back, you can get one easily
var d = m.toDate();

// Or you can use other functions, such as formatting to a string
var s = m.format("YYYY-MM-DD h:mm a");
```

Also, you may want to look into passing an ISO-8601 formatted string from your asp.net page to begin with.  From .Net, use `yourDateTimeOffset.ToString("o")`.  Moment can parse those by default without any extra specifiers.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, i heard about moment but unfortunately i didn't test it. after all i reached to write my own logic to calculate dateTime and offset from string formatted in my way. it's work now but i try to test moment asap and i will write about my experience with it just here. Anyway i accept your reply as answer. Thanks again and Good luck.